# Java ThreadLocal static?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-local

Setting a value in Thread Local:

```
//Class A holds the static ThreadLocal variable.

    Class A{

    public static ThreadLocal<X> myThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<X>();             
    ....
    }


//A Class B method sets value in A's static ThreadLocal variable 
    class B{
    {
         public void someBmethod(){
             X x = new X();
             A.myThreadLocal.set(x);
         }
    }


//Class C retrieves the value set in A's Thread Local variable.

    Class C {

    public void someCMethod(){
         X x = A.myThreadLocal.get();
    }
    ...
    }
```

**Quesiton**: 
Now assuming this is a web-application, and threads execute: B.someBMethod, C.someCMethod in that order.

Multiple threads executing B's someBMethod, will end up updating the **SAME** A's static ThreadLocal variable myThreadLocal, thereby beating the very purpose of ThreadLocal variable. (Using static for ThreadLocal is what is recommended as per documentation.)

The C's someCMethod, while retrieving value from ThreadLocal may not get the value set by the 'current' thread.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As per the definition of [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) class

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ
> from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one
> (via its get or set method) **has its own, independently initialized
> copy of the variable.** ThreadLocal instances are typically private
> static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread
> (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

That means say 2 threads `t1` & `t2` executes `someBMethod()` and they end up setting `x1` & `x2`(Instances of `X`) respectively. Now when `t1` comes and executes `someCMethod()` it gets `x1` (which is **set** by **itself** earlier) and `t2` gets `x2`.

In other words, its safe to have a single static instance of `ThreadLocal`, because internally it does something like this when you invoke `set`

```
set(currentThread, value) //setting value against that particular thread
```

and when you invoke get

```
get(currentThread) //getting value for the thread
```

Comment: The need for this class is crucial while creating thread specific singleton objects....

Answer (score 10):

I study the java **source code**,

1. `java.lang.Thread Class` contains a **instance** variable as below.

   `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap threadLocals = null;`

Because `threadLocals` variable is **non-static**, Every thread in a application (i.e., **every instance of Thread Class**) will have it's **own copy** of threadLocals map.

2. **Key** for this map is, **current** ThreadLocal instance, and **value** is the value which you pass as **argument** to ThreadLocal.set().
3. When you try to **fetch** value as `ThreadLocal.get()` , internally, it will fetch from the ThreadLocalMap of **Current Thread**.

**In simple terms**, you are getting & setting values from/to your current **Thread** Object, **not** from/to your **ThreadLocal** object.

Answer (score 7):

> Multiple threads executing B's someBMethod, will end up updating the SAME A's static ThreadLocal variable myThreadLocal

Yes, they operate on the same object. However, it is important to realize that the way `ThreadLocal` works is that each thread has its own, separate value. Thus if you have ten threads writing to `myThreadLocal` and then reading from `myThreadLocal`, each will see the correct (i.e. their own) value.

To put it another way, it does not matter which class or object writes to an instance of `ThreadLocal`. What matters is the *thread* in whose context the operation is performed.

Answer (score 2):

> Multiple threads executing B's someBMethod, will end up updating the SAME A's static ThreadLocal variable myThreadLocal

No they won't. Every thread has its own instance of the contained variable of type X.

> thereby beating the very purpose of ThreadLocal variable

No.

Have another look at the Javadoc.

Comment: The Java Doc is extremely unclear, hence he asked that question, and hence why I'm here reading the questions and answers :D

Comment: The very name `ThreadLocal` answers your question, let alone the Javadoc. The extract provided by @NimChimpsky alone is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

No they won't, thats the point. [Javadoc :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

> These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each
>   thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own,
>   independently initialized copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances
>   are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate
>   state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).