# Is it thread safe to change Mongo collection for Spring Data Repositories from static ThreadLocal variable?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I wanted to use Spring Data Mongo repositories and specify collection of the document at runtime.
I found the way how I can achieve it in this ticket [DATAMONGO-525](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-525) and what I did:

Created GenericObject with ThreadLocal variable and linked collection name with 
 this static variable:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "#{T(com.test.myproject.model.GenericObject).getCollection()}")
public class GenericObject {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> collection = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private org.bson.Document doc;

    public static void setCollection(String type) {
        collection.set(type);
    }

    public static String getCollection() {
        return collection.get();
    }

}
```

I created GenericRepository for GenericObject:

```
public interface GenericObjectRepository extends MongoRepository<GenericObject, ObjectId> {
}
```

So, now when I want to get/save/delete GenericObject from specific collection I should specify collection before each request:

```
// save
GenericObject obj = new GenericObject();
GenericObject.setCollection(collectionName);
genericObjectRepository.save(obj)
...
//get
GenericObject.setCollection(collectionName);
genericObjectRepository.findById(new ObjectId(id))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RecordNotFoundException("GOS00001", id, collection));
```

The question is:

Is my approach is thread safe? Are there any issues that I don't see?

SpringDataMongoDB version: **2.0.5.RELEASE**

Comment: @OliverGierke, Is DATAMONGO-525 in the latest release? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're almost better off just using [MongoOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html) directly. Why bother with worrying with `ThreadLocal`. If you want to see more info about static ThreadLocal usage you can refer to this question: [Java ThreadLocal static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249687/java-threadlocal-static) But yeah you're approach is fine. ThreadLocal is safe to use as a different thread can't set ThreadLocal of another thread.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Strelok, The challenge was to use MongoRepositories without implementing CRUD operations with MongoTemplate or MongoOperations. And I just wanna be sure that there won't be any side effects from spring.